# MSXML problem in VC++ 6

Tags: c++, com, msxml

I have this bit of code:

```
typedef CComQIPtr<MSXML::IXMLDOMDocument2> XML_DocumentPtr;
```

then inside some class:

```
XML_DocumentPtr m_spDoc;
```

then inside some function:

```
XML_NodePtr rn=m_spDoc->GetdocumentElement();
```

I cannot find anywhere in the MSDN documentation what that `GetDocumentElement()` is supposed to do?  Can anyone tell me why it doesn't seem to be part of `IXMLDOMDocument2` interface?

And which interface does have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IXMLDocument2` inherits from `IXMLDocument`. The `GetDocumentElement()` method is defined in that interface. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757878(v=VS.85).aspx).

Basically `GetdocumentElement` returns the root element of the XML document.

> The property is read/write. It returns
>   an IXMLDOMElement that represents the
>   single element that represents the
>   root of the XML document tree. It
>   returns Null if no root exists.
>
> When setting the documentElement
>   property, the specified element node
>   is inserted into the child list of the
>   document after any document type node.
>   To precisely place the node within the
>   children of the document, call the
>   insertBefore method of theIXMLDOMNode.
>
> The parentNode property is reset to
>   the document node as a result of this
>   operation.

Answer (score 0):

`GetdocumentElement` returns the root element of the document or NULL if no root exists.